# Delayed Job error when using DataMapper as backend

Tags: ruby, datamapper, delayed-job

I'm receiving a strange error when using DataMapper as the backend for Delayed Job. I am currently using the following gems:

```
delayed_job, 2.1.0.pre2
delayed_job_data_mapper, 1.0.0.rc
```

According to the instructions found here:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_data_mapper

I can successfully run

```
Delayed::Worker.backend = :data_mapper
Delayed::Worker.backend.auto_upgrade!
```

as well as enqueue objects into the database. However, when I try to run a rake task to run a worker, the workers starts successfully, but then when trying to decide what jobs to pull, gives the following error:

```
rake aborted!
expected a time or date, got Sun Feb 20 11:06:58 -0600 2011
```

It seems that this was previously reported as an issue on Github by someone else, but there's no solution, and the ticket is months old:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_data_mapper/issues#issue/1

[UPDATE] Someone posted an answer to the Github issue, which I have duplicated in my answer below this question.

**So, my question is this: has anyone solved this error? Or is there a different way to do DataMapper + Delayed Job that I'm not aware of?**

Full rake trace:

```
expected a time or date, got Sun Feb 20 11:08:56 -0600 2011
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:94:in `sum'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:33:in `inject'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:86:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:86:in `inject'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:86:in `sum'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:69:in `until'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:255:in `minus_without_coercion'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:268:in `-'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job_data_mapper-1.0.0.rc/lib/delayed/backend/data_mapper.rb:35:in `find_available'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:101:in `work_off'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:100:in `times'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:100:in `work_off'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:75:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:71:in `loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.0.pre2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:71:in `start'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'll be interested to see if anyone comes up to a solution for this, but in the mean time I've decided to go with Resque instead of Delayed Job. It took all of an hour to set up and migrate my existing Delayed Job code to, and since it's Redis I don't have to worry about it clogging up my main application database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stefanobernardi on [Github](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_data_mapper/issues#issue/1) gave this answer:

> You need to require
>   "active_support/core_ext"

I haven't had a chance to try this out myself and see if it works since I ended up going with Resque instead, but I thought I would go ahead and post this answer in case anyone else comes across this question and actually wants a solution.